# ExportToXlsx is not exporting data

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have migrated my WinForms application from Dev express 8.2 to 15.2.After migration,I tried to export data from XtraGrid.GridControl using `grdExportToExcel.ExportToXls(strExcelFilePath);` but its opening empty Excel sheet.I am not getting any exception.With the earlier version it worked properly.

Comment: Have you debugged and checked that the grdExportToExcel contains some data just before exporting it?

Comment: Thank you James.I checked it and we have the data.Still Export is not showing any data.

Comment: I think this is a good question for their Support channel.

Comment: Have you tired ExportToXlsOld?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `grdExportToExcel.ForceInitialize();` method before calling export method.It worked for me.Thank you all.